# Interstellar: why is the interior of the black hole dark?

Tags: interstellar

When Cooper crosses Gargantua's event horizon (after detaching from *Endurance*), everything goes pitch black. But why? Cooper should still have been able to see the portion of light from the accretion disk that also crosses the event horizon. Crossing the event horizon simply means that light can't ever get back out, not that it disappears straight away. This is the same reasoning that says that a meteorite that crosses the Earth's event horizon (i.e., the point where the escape velocity of the Earth's gravity well exceeds the velocity of the meteorite) can't get out to space again, but it doesn't disappear or immediately plonk straight down to the ground.

Comment: This question should be here: [Space Exploration Exchange](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Daft If this gets migrated, I think [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) is a better home than Space Exploration.

Comment: @alexwlchan ah I knew there was a more suitable one than space exploration!! Cheers

Comment: Physics might be an ok place for this but be ready to be told your physics understanding is a bit off. The good news is I'm petty sure your misconceptions about event horizons have already been asked and answered. (for reference: the "event horizon" of Earth -- if it had one -- would be about 1 inch across)

Comment: try: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46999/seeing-the-light-in-a-black-hole/47060#47060

Comment: It's dark because they're facing downwards (see the physics-based animations of a fall into a black hole [here](http://jila.colorado.edu/~ajsh/insidebh/schw.html), especially the ones without the artificial grids), if they looked backwards they could still see the accretion disc, but there's nothing to scatter light in space so even if you're near a bright source like the Sun, if you look away to a region without light sources it'll look totally black. And as Michael Edenfield said, the Earth doesn't have an event horizon, though it would if it were sufficiently compressed.

Comment: @phantom42 Tha clause "unless they relate directly to a cited work of fiction" seems kind of silly. I guess science questions are off topic *regardless* of whether they pertain to a cited work?

Comment: @user14111 typically, the dividing line I've seen used has been if the question is trying to rectify the movie against real-world physics, or if it's trying to understand the phsyics in the movie-universe. This is not, however, universally considered. There are a number of questions that should probably be closed based on this measure. A meta discussion may be in order.

Comment: See also: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4963/questions-seeking-scientific-explanations-on-topic

Comment: And yes, as @phantom42 alluded to, the (fuzzy) line between ok and not ok is usually "if the science in question is taken as accurate *within the work*, then don't ask us to explain how that's possible *in the real world*." I think this question is maybe even salvagable, depending on what the OP really wants to know...